# accessing php file on a computer from another computer via internet

Tags: php, iis

i have php files on my computer and i can very well access those from IIS using eighter localhost or loop-back address . But now if i want to access the same file of php from another computer not in the LAN but in a different computer on the internet what should i do? i was thinking of IP address(static) as an option but then i was not successful in finding a way to do the same .
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your question. Is your problem

1) You don't have a static IP? Then:
There are services as "No-IP" where you can create redirects. At their site, you can create a free domain name (which is a static IP as well) such as yourdomain.no-ip.com. Then on your server computer you can run their tool. This tool updates the IP all the time so it will be always correct.

2) You don't know how to access the server from out of the LAN because the IP of your network is the same for all computers (if you're looking from the outside)? Then:
Check your router settings, normally at: http://192.168.1.1. There you will be able to define rules how to redirect requests from the outside. For http, you should redirect requests to port 80 to the IP of the server computer (note: you can even use an other port on the server computer)!

Comment: thanks for the response.see the thing is i dont have a static IP address but thats not an issue as of now because onece i get a way of accesseing php files from another computer i.e not from the LAN i will get a static IP from my ISP.
secondly i am not able to access 192.168.1.1 what username and password should i enter?

Comment: You should ask your provider or router seller about that. People who don't change the data usually have "admin" and "1234" or something similiar. The default values can vary for each router model.

Comment: ok now i did port forwarding and set the port at 3232 and at the same time i set the bindings for IIS on 3232 now can i use my IP address i.e the goabally unique one to access this port and hence the php file???
P.S-i am using IIS to run my php files

Comment: hey andreas thanks a lot for your support i finally have set up a virtual server and it is now accessible from a remote computer.
cheers.